# Appear Login form disappear Login button, and viceversa

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication, button

I want to know if there is a simple way (e.g. using javascript) to make this idea. I have this code (a simple snippet sample):

```
<!-- LOGIN BUTTON -->
<div id="id01" class="text-login_button">
    <h1>Login.</h1>         
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="btn btn-login">Login Form</button>   
</div>

<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
<div id="id02" class="my-form">
    <form class="blablabla" action="" method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>              
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>                
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Well, when I click on "Login Button" appear "Login Form". So far so good.

But now, using **id number** (i.e. **id="01"** for login button and **id="02"** for login form) I want, if possible, to obtain these functions:

1. when I click on "Login Button" (**id="01"**) appear "Login Form" (**id="02"**) but I want that disappear - at the same time - the "Login Button" (**id="01"**);
2. ...and viceversa, when I close "Login Form" (**id="02"**) must appear "Login Button" (**id="01"**) again.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner approach to what you want. You can toggle the div based on it's property and submit the form.

```js
function toggleLoginForm() {
  if (document.getElementById('id02').style.display !== 'block') document.getElementById('id02').style.display = 'block';
  else document.getElementById('id02').style.display = 'none';
}

function formSubmitFunction() {
  document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('id02').style.display = 'none';
  return false;
}
```

```css
.my-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- LOGIN BUTTON -->
<div id="id01" class="text-login_button">
  <h1>Login.</h1>
  <button onclick="toggleLoginForm()" class="btn btn-login">Login Form</button>
</div>

<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
<div id="id02" class="my-form">
  <form class="blablabla" onsubmit="return formSubmitFunction()" action="" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wiil try it.

Comment: Nope, because "Login form" button (and text) doesn't disappear when login form appear. :-)

Comment: You should run the snippet and check it, it's working there.